# How to render a views title in .tpl file?

Tags: views, theming

I embed a view in a .tpl file but it doesn't show the title. It only shows the content.

How to render the **title** of the view?

I'm using the code below:

```
<?php
print views_embed_view('dummy');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way :

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->set_display('display_id');
print $view->get_title();
print $view->preview('display_id');
```